# Why can't the entry point of a dll be found within my program? PE file

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, inject, portable-executable

I'm trying to create a mod loader for an 18 year old game to help me get better at c++. Right now I'm just trying to inject a dll into the same process of the mod loader. The sample dll just prints some text to the command window but doesn't. I think that the code that I have loading the entry point of the dll is not working because everything works up until I call the entry point function of my sample dll within my ModLoader.exe, and Visual Studio just throws an Access Violation. I poked through the memory viewer in debug mode within visual studio to try and see where my ModLoader program thinks the dll entry point is located within the dll but the address just points to a bunch of zeros. I recently learned the PE file format and tried to understand all the code that I wrote when I was following a tutorial on Youtube on how to do this, so forgive me for my inexperience I'm just trying to learn. The other code that I do not show is me locating and finding the target process, reading the dll binary, getting the headers from the dll, me allocating space on the target process for the dll, and finally me writing all of the section header data into the target process. I can provide any other code that y'all would like to see!

Injector.h

```
using ModLoader_LoadLibrary = HINSTANCE(WINAPI*)(const char* filename); 
using ModLoader_GetProcAddress = UINT_PTR(WINAPI*)(HINSTANCE module, const char* procName);
using ModLoader_DllEntry = BOOL(WINAPI*)(HINSTANCE dll, DWORD reason, LPVOID reserved);

struct ModLoader_ManualMapping_Data
{
    ModLoader_LoadLibrary ML_LoadLibrary;       //Function pointer to the windows load library function
    ModLoader_GetProcAddress ML_ProcAddress;    //Function pointer to a function to be called 
    HINSTANCE ML_Module;                            //dll instance
};
```

Injector.cpp : Shellcode function that'll run alongside the target executable

```
    void __stdcall Shellcode(ModLoader_ManualMapping_Data* data)
{
    if (!data)
        return;
BYTE* pData = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(data);

IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER& optHeader = reinterpret_cast<IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*>(pData + reinterpret_cast<IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*>(pData)->e_lfanew)->OptionalHeader;

auto loadLibrary = data->ML_LoadLibrary;
auto procAddress = data->ML_ProcAddress;
auto dllLoad = reinterpret_cast<ModLoader_DllEntry>(pData + optHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint); //Loads entry point func from dll
BYTE* locationDelta = pData - optHeader.ImageBase; //pData = the new address | ImageBase = preferred address -> Get the difference between the two to add to every address in the relocation table
if (locationDelta) //THIS DOES NOT GET RAN
{
    //Adds the delta value to all addresses within the base relocation table 
}

//Import table
if (optHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].Size)
{
    IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR* imgImport = reinterpret_cast<IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR*>(pData
        + optHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress);
    while (imgImport->Name) //THIS DOES NOT GET RAN B\C imgImport is all zeros.
    {
        //Loops through import table
    }
}
if (optHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_TLS].Size) //THIS DOES NOT GET RAN
{
    //Calls the callback functions within dll
}
dllLoad(reinterpret_cast<HINSTANCE>(pData), DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, nullptr); //PROBLEM: ACCESS VIOLATION
}
```

Injector.cpp : bool ManualMapping(HANDLE process, const char* dllFilepath)
-- This function is called in main.cpp.
The srcData variable is just the binary contents of the dll

```
ModLoader_ManualMapping_Data loadData = { 0 };
loadData.ML_LoadLibrary =  LoadLibraryA;
loadData.ML_ProcAddress = reinterpret_cast<ModLoader_GetProcAddress>(GetProcAddress);

memcpy(srcData, &loadData, sizeof(loadData));
WriteProcessMemory(process, locOfDll, srcData, 0x1000, nullptr);
void* shellCodeBase = VirtualAllocEx(process, nullptr, 0x1000, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE); //Allocates 0x1000 bytes in the process memory for the shellcode
WriteProcessMemory(process, shellCodeBase, Shellcode, 0x1000, nullptr); //Injects the Shellcode function into the process
HANDLE thread = nullptr;
thread = CreateRemoteThread(process, nullptr, 0, reinterpret_cast<PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE>(shellCodeBase), locOfDll, 0, nullptr); //Runs
```

Finally the sample dll code

```
#include <Windows.h>

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hModule, DWORD reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (reason_for_call)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            OutputDebugStringA("Injected!");
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

EDIT
After rewriting all the code and looking at it all day I finally figured it out. I just had to make sure that the parameters were right when I called dllLoad!

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Make sure it's **minimal** ***and*** **complete**.

Comment: Fixed the post to be minimal and complete! Sorry about that

Comment: In your posted code, you are not checking the return values of many functions. That way, you will not notice if any of the functions fail. I would, for example, consider it important to always check the return values of `WriteProcessMemory` and `VirtualAllocEx`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I went ahead and did all of that but when I call dllLoad in the Shellcode function I'm still getting an error.

Comment: `pData + optHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint` - pData is a pointer to your `ModLoader_ManualMapping_Data`. Adding those two values makes no sense